# Linux Issue : Mount point automatically changes from primary to secondary or secondary to primary on reboot in linux, debian 11/12

Tags: linux, debian, disk, fdisk

I am using debian linux , and in this operating system , I am using 2 disk

1 -> Primary disk (/dev/sda1)

2 -> Secondary disk (/dev/sdb1)

First disk is mounted on "/" and the 2nd disk is mounted on /mnt/disk , and the entries of both the disk is defined in fstab file present in /etc.

Every time when I reboot my linux machine , mount points changes automatically , means sometime /dev/sdb1 is attached with / and /dev/sda1 is attached with /mnt/disk and vice-versa.

I have tried so many solutions but failed to find the exact root cause for this issue

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdX` are not fixed. They **will** change between reboots and you can't do much about it. This is caused by asynchronous initialization of devices and there is a race condition; whichever happens to be faster this time claims sda, other one is sdb.

So you should not use names like `/dev/sdX` when building fstab.

Use LABEL, UUID, or `/dev/disk/...` symlinks, which *are* stable, e.g. they identify the device or the filesystem and won't change even if sda and sdb switch roles. Or you can use `/dev/mapper/VG-LV` links if you use LVM, and `/dev/md/X` if you use MD RAID; those use UUIDs under the hood and also are stable.

For example:

```
UUID=cac830eb-9fd6-4161-989d-71be3a055978 /boot ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/system-debian / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

If the filesystem has this UUID it will be mounted as /boot, period. I don't care if it happens to be sda1, sdb1 or whatever. The root file system is on LVM and will always appear at `/dev/mapper/system-debian` because it's a LV `debian` on the VG `system`.

To know your UUIDs, LABELs and so on, run `blkid` (as root or with sudo).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply.  Solution works..Really appreciated